# How to get TCL http package 2.8 and install on tcl 8.3. I am using http::geturl and need to change the method to PUT

Tags: http, tcl, put

I need the `http::geturl -method` option to do a PUT.  I am using tcl8.3 and http package 2.4.  I need http package 2.8 to use the `-method` option.  Where do I get the package, where do I put it (tcl8.3 folder?), and is it compatible with tcl8.3?

Comment: Er... Why are you using a 20 year old version of tcl?

Comment: I found what I think is the first 2.8.0 version of http.tcl. It's just a plain Tcl file, but it does `package require Tcl 8.6` -- https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/artifact/e8851a4270fb7fd5 -- it was checked-in in April 2009.

Comment: Thanks … do you think it would work if I change in my http.tcl the following

Comment: elseif {$state(-validate)} {
 set how HEAD to elseif {$state(-validate)} {
 set how PUT

Comment: In a former job, I was stuck on a Tcl 8.0p2 version that was embedded into the database product we used, so upgrading was impossible. Are you in a similar situation, or is it possible to upgrade a standalone Tcl installation? If you can't upgrade, your only option is to read the current http code, see how PUT is implemented, and implement it yourself in your copy of http.tcl.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an unsupported version of Tcl. (Good grief! 8.3? That's a blast from the past!) Tcl 8.4 is also unsupported (support effectively stopped in 2013), and 8.5 is only really supported for existing code and should not be used for new work. You don't *have* to switch to 8.6… but it's **strongly recommended** that you do for many reasons (such as it being a version that actually builds with current toolchains!)

The package you are interested in, `http`, is shipped as an integrated part of Tcl. It's not intended for separate use, and newer versions make use of basic Tcl features that are not supported in older versions of the language as they use features like coroutines and decompression streams. However, [the `-method` option is supported in 8.5](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/http.htm) onwards so you have a range of upgrade options and you can therefore use any currently supported version.

<sup>(FWIW, the feature that you're asking for was added about *12 years ago.* Insisting on sticking with 8.3 — or 8.4 for that matter — is *really* sticking with the time pod beyond all common sense.)</sup>

Comment: The version of http in 8.5 is unlikely to work with Tcl 8.3 anyway, and if you forced it in it would be a wholly unsupported configuration. Apparently it could work with 8.4… but we never distributed it like that and ***nobody should be stuck with code that old*** (unless it's deployed to a spacecraft or something).